# Python: for loop iteration through objects, not strings

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I used `pd.GetDummies` to one hot encode my categorical variables to be used as predictors. For some of my columns that had many unique values, I have many new columns and I am trying to find a fast way to create interaction terms for these. (I only want interactions for a subset of my columns, so `PolynomialFeatures()` won't work...or will it?)

Here is what I am trying to do:

**Step 1**: Create lists of column names for each of the subset I want to multiply:

```
channel = [col for col in df if col.startswith('channel')]
quote = [col for col in df if col.startswith('quote')]

print(channel[:1])
Out: 'channel_A'
     'channel_B'
```

**Step 2**: for loop:

```
cols = 'channel quote'.split()
for col in cols:
    for i in col:
        colname = 'value_X_'+i
        df[colname] = df['value_days']*df[i]+0
```

The problem is that the inner loop does not recognize `col` as an object: it recognizes it as a string (error = `'c'`, evidenced by:

```
for col in cols:
    for i in col:
        print i

Out[1]: 
c
h
.
.
.
o
t
e
```

**Goal**: My desired outcome is to get a new column that is *named* for the two columns were originally multiplied and has *values* for the multiplication.

For example, the first element in channel is `channel_A`, so I want to get a new column named `value_X_channel_A` and it should have values that are equivalent to the product of `value_days`*`channel_A`.

```
value_days | channel_A | value_X_channel_A
-------------------------------------------
5          |5          |25
```

This works perfectly fine if I just run the inner loop and replace `col` with `channel`.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String are objects....and you are iterating character (I.e c,h,a,n) inside a string (I.e channel, quote), what do you expect to get?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that @Marcus.Aurelianus. I edited the question to answer this.

Comment: delete line 'for i in col:' ,  and try?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't get the unique names of each column. That would just give me `channel`, but the actual column names are `channel_A`, `channel_B`, and so on. That's the reason for the inner loop: I need to loop through the list of column names starting with `'channel'`.

Comment: ok, you're hard on using for loops? can't you just put the processing in a function and apply it to the dataframe?

Comment: @skrubber, thanks for the suggestion. That would probably work, but I'm still very new to python and programming in general, so I have no idea how to do what you're suggesting. Can you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is worded in a way that is hard to understand (for me at least). If I'm right about what you want, you wish to multiply each column with a name starting with "channel" or "quote" by the column "value_days" stored in your df, and then store that in a new column named value_X_{i} where {i} is the name of the column that was multiplied. You're close, but you're code is awkward. Use another data structure (Dictionary) to make the code straightforward and readable:

```
d = { 
    'quote' : [col for col in df if col.startswith('quote')],
    'channel' : [col for col in df if col.startswith('channel')]
}

for columns_string, columns in d.items():
    for col_string in columns:
        colname = 'value_X_'+col_string
        df[colname] = df['value_days'] * df[i] + 0
```

Explanation:

`d = ...` - Creates a dictionary with two key value pairs 'quote' and 'channel' with values equal to a list of the desired column names.

`for column_string, columns in d.items():` - .items() returns an iterator to a dictionaries key/value pairs, we then loop through this naming each key 'column_string' and the column-names-list is stored in the variable 'columns'.

You can quickly realize that something is wrong with your code by noticing that you create variables `channel` and `quote` and set them to there corresponding values, but you never actually use either of those lists in your code.

Comment: yeah, the poor wording of my question reflects how comfortable I am with coding. I need to get better at using dictionaries and this is a perfect example of how useful they can be. Thanks for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: @NLR glad I could help. Dictionaries are bread and butter in Python, they're extremely flexible and can be applied to solve endless numbers of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see, in your function you are basically calling 'channel' string. But to loop through value from channel variable, you need to convert string to variable with vars function first.

Example:

```
channel=['channel_A','channel_B']
quote=['quote_A','quote_B']

cols = 'channel quote'.split()

for col in cols:
    var=vars()[col]
    for ele in var:
        print(ele)
```

Output:

```
channel_A
channel_B
quote_A
quote_B
```

for your function, change it to:

```
cols = 'channel quote'.split()
for col in cols:
    for i in vars()[col]:
        colname = 'value_X_'+i
        df[colname] = df['value_days']*df[i]+0
```

Feel free to ask if you are still not clear.

Comment: I feel as if it's bad practice to access variables in this way if it's not necessary. I could be wrong but that just seems like an awkward way to do it.

Comment: @YungGun, basically it is the data structure OP used.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Marcus.Aurelianus

Comment: @YungGun, he tends to use a variable to represent all the strings start with that name, channel = [col for col in df if col.startswith('channel')]
quote = [col for col in df if col.startswith('quote')]

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. Even if using `vars()` isn't ideal, I learned that this function exists, which is a big help in and of itself.